# Bash sed function not working on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, sed

Can anyone tell me how to change this command:

```
sed -i.bak "/group :test/ a gem 'selenium-webdriver'" Gemfile
```

To work on Mac?
Getting this error:

```
sed: 1: "/group :test/ a gem 'se ...": command a expects \ followed by text
```

I was trying to do a\ but didn't help.

Comment: Did you type your command it properly? Is there a space between the -i and the .bak or is that just a typo putting it into SO?

Comment: Tried with & without space.

Comment: It adds a line after another line. Works on Linux.

Comment: OS X user land is a BSD derivative and uses BSD sed.  It does not implement the GNU extensions.

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using the `a` command, i.e. with whitespace separating `a` from the text to insert, is [a GNU `sed` extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands). The portable way to do it is with a backslash, followed by a newline:

```
$ echo 'group :test' | sed "/group :test/ a\\
gem 'selenium-webdriver'"
group :test
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

Make sure that the backslash is quoted correctly, so that it is passed to `sed`, rather than being swallowed by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could do the same thing in awk:

```
cp Gemfile Gemfile.bak
awk '1;/group :test/{print "gem '"'"'selenium-webdriver'"'"'"}' Gemfile > tmp && mv tmp Gemfile
```

The `1` at the start means that every line in the file is printed. The line is appended when the pattern is matched.

To get quotes in your string, you have to close single quotes, write a single quote within double quotes, then reopen single quotes to continue the awk command. Simple ;)